# Editing a jQuery script so the new version has code I need to make a gallery work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read a post answer that you can do search for the code I need from an old version of jQuery and copy it and paste it into a newer version jQuery script. This way I don't have to try and have two versions of jQuery to load at the same time which was unsuccessful. Both the jQuery scripts I have are .min

How do I do this? See the person's answer below

Why would you need two jQuery libraries anyway?! Just use the newer one! ... Let's even say you needed the old one because you need some functions that aren't available in the new framework. Just look them up in search mode and copy past them one by one to the new framework (can only be done if you use jQuery offline like me, which saves loading time during developpement cause it gets cached.) P.S: I hope this doesn't cause any copyrights infrigments.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. [Please take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get an idea of how to properly ask a question to have the best shot at getting the answer you desire. Main points: i) what have you tried already (show code), ii) what output are you seeing, iii) what output are you looking to get, iv) and what research have you done on the topic?

Comment: who ever told you that is not a good practice, should never touch whats in the library files. they meant to be if they meant to be out on the newer version. Always best to change your code to adapt to the newer version otherwise one day, you need to change the whole, because the browser started not supporting what ever the old version of codes you were using. At least if you know what to update in your code, trying finding new solution for it. ADAPT!!! and CHANGE!

Answer (score 0):

Editing jquery is very bad practice, do it only for very small projects which maintenance won't have any work with jquery or component updates at all!

Better try using Jquery Noconflict library.